# Using count(*) and mysql_fetch_object() at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count all the rows and at the same time list them as I usually do, using `mysql_fetch_object`. I thought I'd do something like this;

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS totalfound FROM img WHERE state='0'");
```

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the values out - I just get the first item in the table when I run this;

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($total)) { echo $record->id; }
```

If I want to get the totalfound I could do this;

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($total);
$count = $result['totalfound'];
```

...but then I can't get the rest. I know I'm thinking wrong but can't seem to get it to work. Can you guys please help me out? Thanks!

**Once thing I forgot to mention: mysql_num_rows is too slow, I was thinking of using count(*) instead. As an example, mysql_num_rows on the entire table takes everything from 3 to 9 seconds, and a count(*) always takes 0.6 seconds, getting the same results.**

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs, I forgot to write that I want to use count(*) because it's way faster than mysql_num_rows.

Comment: yeah, CodeCaster is right. The key question is - what you 're trying to count and what for?

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone, I've solved it with your help & double queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `count` is an aggregate function, you cannot select both rows and aggregates without using `group by`. MySQL will let you do it without the `group by`, and will produce unpredictable results.

Just use the query without `count` to get the rows, and use `mysql_num_rows()` on the result.

**Edit**: If `mysql_num_rows()` is slow, you must be returning a lot of rows. You'd then better execute two queries, one simply `select count(*) as numrows ...`, and one to retreive your data.

Try to add proper indexes and the `count(*)` will execute within a few miliseconds.

You really don't want this in one query. Every row will then have a column that states how many rows there are, which is unrelated to that row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention that I don't want to use mysql_num_rows. The question has been updated.

Comment: This solution is golden, especially if you're using a transaction-aware engine (like InnoDB) and doing the `COUNT(*)` and `SELECT *` in the same transaction. (Or if you don't care the count may be slightly inaccurate).

Answer (score 3):

Why not just list them normally and get the count by the inbuilt function?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img WHERE state='0'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //do your thing here
}
```

**Editing in response to your edit**

In normal circumstances, where you only want the Count, a Count(*) would be far faster than `mysql_num_rows()` because Count(*) would only return the count. In your case, since you want the records anyway, `mysql_num_rows()` should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention that I don't want to use mysql_num_rows. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you need, I think you could use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img WHERE state='0'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

With `$result` you can get all rows the way you're used to, while `$num_rows` has the number of returned rows from database.

Comment: If `state` is integer type, then just use `state=0`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention that I don't want to use mysql_num_rows. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the Marco's right answer,
why can't you make it the same way, `echo $record->totalfound;`?

As for the "mysql_num_rows being slow" - it is no more a delusion.
*You have just heard something* but didn't get the point.

mysql_num_rows itself isn't being slow by any means.
it is **gathering data rows** being slow, not getting them count.

mysql_num_rows indeed is slower than count(*) **if you need only that number, not all the data**

but if you are getting your data anyway, **mysql_num_rows is exactly what you need**

Comment: Thanks for your reply... And for deleting that comment of yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use KISS theory and do the below

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($total)) {$totalData[] = $record; }
count($totalData) // returns total number of rows
```

[`Count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 0):

My dear haven't you listen about [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img WHERE state='0'");
$total_found=mysql_num_rows($total);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention that I don't want to use mysql_num_rows. The question has been updated.